# jquery returns no data from query, throws error null or not an object

Tags: jquery

```
 var instance = new readers_cls();
 var theID = $('#theID').val();
 var thedata = instance.getReaderNumbers(theID);

 $.each(thedata.data, function(){
 $('#theReader').append('<tr class="readerRow"id="new' + index + '"><td align="center"><input type="text" id="reader' + index + '" name="reader' + index + '" value="' + this.readernumber + '" class="readerName"></td></tr>');
                    index++;
                });
```

Works fine if I actually have data returned but throws error when returns no data, not sure how to test for the null or not and object on the .each

Comment: What do you want to do if it IS null, add blank rows or no row at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
if(thedata.data) {
    $.each(thedata.data, function(){
        $('#theReader').append('<tr class="readerRow"id="new' + index + '"><td align="center"><input type="text" id="reader' + index + '" name="reader' + index + '" value="' + this.readernumber + '" class="readerName"></td></tr>');
                index++;
            });
}
```